# Is any way to integrate React using npm into SharePoint 2016 add-in

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-2013

I want to integrate react in SharePoint add-in I have tried with direct cdn react-dom links but I want to integrate via NPM so I can use many shared react components and library.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no, addin is a project based on .net. You can try to use SPFX, although the version of SPFX supported by SharePoint 2016 is relatively low.
[image]
[image]